# User-friendly xml sensitization library that html encodes invalid parts of user submissions?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I would like to allow my users to submit a subset of xhtml that will be displayed to other users (likely I'll build a schema for it) but I want the server to handle validation more gracefully then hard rejecting invalid submissions. Instead I'd like the server to Html Encode invalid/harmful parts of the submissions (sanitize javascript and css etc.).

Is there any library (maybe asp.net mvc 2 has such functionality?) or do I have to develop my own?

Or maybe there is a javascript library that html encodes invalid parts and I can just have the server only accept that subset?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [Anti-XSS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=051ee83c-5ccf-48ed-8463-02f56a6bfc09&displaylang=en). See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396324/sanitize-html-encoded-text-decimal-notation-from-antixss-v3-output) for relevant tips.

Answer (score 0):

You could decorate the action you are posting to with the [`[ValidateInput]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx) attribute in order to accept dangerous characters:

```
[ValidateRequest(false)]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

And when the moment comes to show them on a page make sure you HTML encode them:

```
<%= Html.Encode(Model.SomeProperty) %>
```

or using the new syntax in ASP.NET 4:

```
<%: Model.SomeProperty %>
```

Also if you are using ASP.NET 4 make sure you put the following in your web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

or the `ValidateRequest` attribute might [not be taken into account](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pintyo/archive/2010/03/24/simple-rtfem-or-why-asp-net-mvc-validateinput_3D00_false-doesnt-disable-request-validation-on-asp-net-4.aspx).